# How is this series series feedback topology forOPAMP?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, negative-feedback

[image]
This is stated as series series type of negative feedback but why.

Whereas this one is series shunt topology
[image]

Comment: The 1st has the output load in series with R to provide current limit but does not share ground  return like the shunt output.. The 1st is a also voltage to current converter dependant on load R

Comment: If i guess what you mean to say is if current through load resistance is considered zero then feedback voltage is observed ,is it that you meant.

Comment: No the OA input current is always assumed zero with 0Vdiff, so the current flows only thru the resistor paths from source and output

Comment: Yes input current has to be zero but load current can occur due to output voltage.Is the current through load what you considered / made zero to find the type of sampling in the above circuits.

Comment: yes the 1st uses series current source Vin/R thru RL to achieve gain 1+ RL/R while second uses shunt  voltage source with same gain 1+R2/R1 independent of RL

Comment: Both of them appear series to me since both are the same circuits. If you swap the ground and the \$v_I\$ terminal then the second case would act like a shunt feedback.

Comment: Yes - both realize , of course, the same feedback scheme. Both are series-shunt feedback. At the differential input, the input signal is added (in series) with the feedback signal, which is derived from the output where (in parallel....shunt) a load could be connected. Remark: I do not like this terminology at all...it sounds confusing to me. Instead I prefer "voltage-controilled voltage feedback".